# lavalamp with rails not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, lavalamp

I am trying to get lavalamp to work under a rails envrioment but i I thik there is a conflict with Gemfile:gem 'jquery-rails','3.1.2'.

Is there away way in which to prove this apart from attempting to create a project without jquery_rails and a simplified Gemfile?

The page works when not under a rails environment.

I have tried http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ but this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Any errors in the web-console?

Comment: looks like I am getting undefinded  is not a fuction on this installJqueryAjaxSuccessPageUpdateTrigger and two anonymous funtions